# FrameLayout not use the styles correctly

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-styles, android-framelayout

I am very happy with this website. I'm learning a lot.

Today I doubt has arisen. And I want to put a style to a FrameLayout. and do not use.

The style is as follows:

```
<style name="textAsk">
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">88dp</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">36dp</item>
        <item name="android:textSize" >18dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">12dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginTop">5dp</item>
    </style>
```

I show fragments that are changing in a FrameLayout. Each Fragment contains a TextView with a text in it.

There are a lot of fragments, and I would like to set a style, a common one, for all the TextViews, in order to save time and not setup the style in each TextView.

I had tried this code:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragmentaskGRP1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    style="@style/textAsk"/>
```

But the only thing that works for me is:

```
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
```

Thank you very much for everything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `FrameLayout` doesn't support the `textColor` or `textSize` attribute ([API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)). So it's never set for the FrameLayout and ignored. See the style properties section from  the guide [Styles and Themes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#Properties) for more information.

Quote from the Guide:

> However, if you apply a style to a View that does not support all of the style properties, the View will apply only those properties that are supported and simply ignore the others.

Define the text-related styles in a separate style definition and use it for this one for the matching views like `TextView`

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that child views don't inherit styles from their enclosing `ViewGroup`. Styles can have parents, but in your case `TextView`s are not going to get these attributes from the `FrameLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

The other styles will not be applied to fragments. You have to create another logic to apply styles to all fragments (Most probably you will have to apply styles  individually to each fragment)

`FrameLayout` have nothing to do with text so `textColor, textSize` will have no effect.

Where as `minWidth, minHeight` are properties of View it think they should work.